# How to Implement Pulse Communication Receiver Code through Single Bus for Pulse Communication

Tags: c

There is a single bus communication protocol that uses pulses. The sender sends data every 3 seconds, and it is proven to be 0 if it is low within 10ms, and 1 if it is high for 6ms if it is high within 10ms. How can the receiver code be written to obtain the transmitted data when there is no data transmission?

```
void pulse_comm_handle(void)
{
    uint8_t stream[30];

    memset(stream, 0xFF, 30);
    p.change_time = GetSysTickMs();

    uint16_t i = 0;
    uint8_t flag = 0;
    while (i < 30)
    {
        if (flag == 8)
        {
            flag = 0;
            rt_kprintf("%d\n", stream[i]);
            i++;
        }
        
        if (rt_pin_read(p.pin) == 0 && GetSysTickMs() >= p.change_time + 10)
        {
            p.change_time = GetSysTickMs();
            stream[i] &= ~(0x80 >> flag);
            flag++;
        }
        
        if (rt_pin_read(p.pin) == 1 && GetSysTickMs() > p.change_time  + 3)
        {
            flag++;
            p.change_time  += 10;
        }
    }

    pulse_flag = 0;
}
```

This is the implementation of my current code. What is the problem?

Comment: How about you start by describing the _actual_ issue. Does your code crash? Does it produce the wrong output? What exactly is the input? Normally with timing-based circuits you have a common clock pulse to reference off. If this communication is between two unsynchronized devices, it's common for the clock to be signalled in some way (e.g. a short pulse or a state transition), followed by the actual value some time after that. I do notice that if `flag` is 8 and `i` is 29, you'll happily increment `i` which means writing to `stream[i]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: "_What is the problem?_" We don't know, please tell us.